# Issue with loading mobile specific custom single page layout in mobile

Tags: theme-development, single, mobile

Hello I am in the middle of theme development which has specific layouts for mobile, I built a custom function to [detect mobile](http://mobiledetect.net/) and load mobile specific layouts in mobile view ports.

Here is the function I wrote to load mobile templates in mobile view ports

```
function theme_mobile_templates($template) {

    global $user_ID, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $new_template = $template;

    // no need to redirect when in admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $template;

    if ( theme_load_mobile()){

        $filename       = basename($template);

        $child_path     = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/mobile' . '/' . $filename;
        $parent_path    = get_template_directory() . '/' . $filename;

        if ( file_exists($child_path) ){
            $new_template = $child_path;
        } else if ( file_exists( $parent_path )){
            $new_template = $parent_path;
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
        }       
    }

    return $new_template;
}
```

// Theme load mobile function - this function is to detect mobile view ports

```
function theme_load_mobile(){
    global $isMobile;
    $detector = new Theme_MobileDetect();
    $isMobile = apply_filters( 'theme_is_mobile', ( $detector->isIphone() || $detector->isAndroid() || $detector->isWindowsphone() ) ? true : false );  
    if ( $isMobile ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function works for the all the page layouts, but it's not working for single layouts. Could not figure how to load single layouts in mobile.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would need a wider view of your code. What is `theme_load_mobile()`? How and when do you execute `theme_mobile_templates($template)`? What is `$template`? How do you load the template returned by `theme_mobile_templates($template)`?

Comment: @cybmet `function theme_load_mobile(){
 global $isMobile;
 $detector = new Theme_MobileDetect();
 $isMobile = apply_filters( 'baloba_is_mobile', ( $detector->isIphone() || $detector->isAndroid() || $detector->isWindowsphone() ) ? true : false ); 
 if ( $isMobile ){
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}` This is the theme_load_mobile function, this is based on http://mobiledetect.net/,   $template is the template files in WordPress Themes,

Comment: Add your code in your question please. It is unreadable in comments :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Added :)

Comment: More information is still needed. We can not see how/when you execute `theme_mobile_templates($template)`, what `$template` is or how you are trying to load the template returned `theme_mobile_templates` when you are in single view. Without that information is impossible to know what happens.

Comment: +1 for @cybmeta In short, which hook are you using to call `theme_mobile_templates()`? Are you using [`'template_include'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) If so, are you sure that a mobile template exists for any non-mobile template? E.g. if you have a `single.php` are you sure that a `/mobile/single.php` exists?